# How to avoid overlapping of labels in a NMDS plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan, ggrepel

I tried to avoid overlapping of labels in a NMDS plot by using the `ggrepel` package. At first my code was like this:

```
result <- adonis(spiders~Wald, data = env, permutations=1000)
result1 <- metaMDS(spiders, distance = "bray", k = 2)
fit <- envfit(result1, env, perm = 1000)

fig<-plot(result1, type = "none")
points(fig, "sites", pch = as.numeric(env$Wald))
text(fig, "species", font=c(2), cex=c(0.75))
plot(fit, p.max = 0.05, col = "darkgrey", font=c(2), cex=c(0.75))
legend("topright", legend = c("Bestand A", "Bestand B", "Bestand C"),cex = 
c(0.75), pch = as.numeric(env$Wald))
```

And I received this plot

[image: NMDS-plot]

so I changed my code slightly

```
fig<-plot(result1, type = "none")
points(fig, "sites", pch = as.numeric(env$Wald))
geom_text_repel(fig, "species", font=c(2), cex=c(0.75))
plot(fit, p.max = 0.05, col = "darkgrey", font=c(2), cex=c(0.75))
```

but than I got this

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character.

I would love to provide my data to make it more easy to answer my question but I don't know how

Comment: I think that `ggrepel` only works with ggplot2 plots, whereas you are using base graphics. It is possible. The `ggvegan` package helps.

Comment: It is available from github at  https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan

Comment: I can't install the pacage

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggvegan’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)

And on the University computers I'm not allowed to install a new R version

Comment: Base graphics in **vegan** have tools to avoid overlapping labels. Old people say that if everything else fails, consult the documentation. In this case it is in the vegan FAQ (it's been asked before) that you can read with `browseVignettes("vegan")`. See the section on "How to avoid cluttered ordination graphs?".

Comment: With help oft he FAQ page I rewrote my code 
    fig<-ordiplot(result1, type = "none")
    orditorp(fig, "sites", pch = as.numeric(env$Wald))
    orditorp(fig, "species", font=c(2), cex=c(0.75))
    plot(fit, p.max = 0.05, col = "darkgrey", font=c(2), cex=c(0.75))

and it looks much better now!
https://imgur.com/a/v3wCc

but now I have a new problem. The sites of my plot are now represented by numbers and I would love them to be symbols like in the image in my question. 
I’m pretty shure the solution is totally banal but I coldn’t find a solution